# Behavior of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am implementing AsyncTask for my understanding of concepts. The code is working but not in way I want to. I have gone through the documents but cannot pin point what wrong am I doing.

Code:

```
private class NewThread extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer , String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Log.d(TAG,"inside doInBackground");
            for (int i=0;i<params.length;i++)
            {
                 try {
                publishProgress(i);
                    Thread.sleep(6000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return "Finished";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"inside onPostExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done " + values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"inside onProgressUpdate");
        }
```

I only see  `Done 0` and `Finished`. What I was expecting is Done0 , Finished, Done1, Finished, Done2. Finished.... OR Done0 Done1 Done2 ....Finished.

What should I change in code to do that? Is it even possible?

I am calling AsyncTask using a button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new NewThread().execute(4);


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you have definitely missed out the part of your code where you call `AsyncTask`, and which is required to understand what you did wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I am using a button to call it. Added code on how to call it.

Comment: The answers below are correct but conceptually what you are missing is that the arguments to execute() are passed to doInBackground as an array. So, when you are calling execute with 4 and expecting it to do your loop 4 times, it is only doing it once because you are checking the length of the array which is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use to start the `AsyncTask` starts 1 (one) instance, passing `4` as a parameter. Therefore, `param.length()` is 1 (one) and you get only one output.

Try this instead:

```
new NewThread().execute(1,2,3,4);
```

Or maybe this, if you want to see several threads working simultaneously:

```
new NewThread().execute(1);
new NewThread().execute(2);
new NewThread().execute(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code to call the a sync task this is just a guess. Looks like you aren't using the params value quite right. It should be:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < params[0]; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Log.d(TAG,"inside doInBackground");
            for (int i=0;i<params.length;i++)
```

to

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer myCount) {
            Log.d(TAG,"inside doInBackground");
            for (int i=0;i<myCount;i++)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you that is it. Such a silly mistake. I feel dirty for asking this question now.

Comment: happens to me all the time :-) x :-)

Answer (score 1):

Async task is correctly executed. You are passing an array with one item and in the loop you are checking for the lenth of the array which is 1 so you get only one "print".

Either in the loop replace

Also one more minor mistake, you expect done 0, done 1 .. to be printed .
But your statement is "Done " + values[0] , which will always print the same statement :)